# Loading huge data efficiently in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory

I have a million rows data set in the following format

```
User Gameid Count
A  1  2
A  2  3
A  10 2
A  8 2
B 10 2
B 1 6

....
```

I want to create a sparse matrix from this with each row representing a user and the columns representing the gameid and the value in each cell is the count of the corresponding user and gameid.

The matrix is sparse. So it should be handled by matlab.

How can I directly load such data without iterating through each line which will take a lot of time. Any suggestions how to do it efficiently?

This is what I want

```
Column 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
       2 3           2    2
       6                  2
```

Comment: Note that a table of size 1 million by 3 is not exactly huge for matlab. `rand(1e6,3)` runs in the blink of an eye. Even iterating over 1 million lines wont take much time. The only thing you should look out for is not blowing it up to 1e6 x 1e5 or so by giving every user a column. (But of course with sparse that would still be managable)

Answer (score 1):

ok your file is file.txt

Ok so with an easy manipulation you can get what u want:

```
clear all
close all

fil = 'file.txt';

fid = fopen(fil,'r');

s = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
s = s{1};
s = s(2:end);

ls = length(s);

fmat = '%s %u %u';

C = sscanf(char(s)',fmat); 
C = reshape(C,[3 length(s)])';
A = char(C(:,1));
data = cellstr(A);
data(:,2:3) = num2cell(C(:,2:3));

Users = unique(A);

S_MAT_DATA = spalloc(length(Users),max(C(:,2)),round(ls/length(Users))+1);

nmat = 1;

for aa = 1:length(Users)
    data_user = cell2mat(data(strncmp(Users(aa),data(:,1),1),2:3)');
    S_MAT_DATA(aa,data_user(1,:)) = data_user(2,:);
end
```

Comment: Actually, that's not what I want.What I want is each user A has a single row which has value 2 in the first column, 3 in the second row,2 in the 10th row and 2 in the 8th row.

Comment: Thats a pretty easy manipulation after uve done what I set out above. My code shows u what u asked and that was how to read in a bunch of data without going line by line?

Comment: Also could you read your comment before posting it it makes no sense??

Comment: I didn't get how that is an easy manipulation. I have to go through each row in the cell line by line and then do it. It will take me a lot of time for billion records

Comment: firstly what do u mean each user has a single row then u say value 3 in the second row?? then the number 2 in the 10th row and the number 2 in the 8th row????

Comment: Actually, a user is A for example. In the text file he has four records. First record has value 2 for game id 1, second record has value 3 for game id 2 and so on. Now I want to create a matrix in matlab where number of rows = unique users and the columns is the game id. So the four records from the text file for user A will give a single row for user A in the matlab matrix which has rows=num of distinct user and columns=distinct game ids. So user A has a single row in the matrix which has four columns

Comment: I have explained what I want in the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `textscan`.

```
fid = fopen(file);
content = textscan(fid, '%s%d%d');

user = content{1}; % cell
field = content{2}; % vector
count = content{3}; % vector
```